# JS redirect after setting a session var with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, session, redirect, var

Been working on a project that requires me to perform a JS redirect to a page, by setting up a session variable in PHP via an AJAX query, and then checking to make sure the session is set. After a successful check, the redirect URL would then be constructed in JS and the redirection performed.

What I've got so far is:

```
<?php

$v_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$hash = md5($v_ip);

?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : './session.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: "<?php echo $hash; ?>",
    success : function(data){},
    error : function(){}
});
</script>

<script>

<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['allow']))  {

echo "var url = \"url-here/?token=\";
      var token = \"token\";
      var redirect = url.concat(token);";

}

?>

window.location.replace(redirect);

</script>
</head>

</html>
```

And the PHP code that sets the variable:

```
<?php

session_start();

$v_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$hash = md5($v_ip);

if(isset($_POST["$hash"]))   {

$_SESSION['allow'] = true;

}

?>
```

On an initial visit to the page, everything is processed correctly and works up to the point of the actual redirect. The session variable is set, the JS code is correctly outputted in the code of the page, and for some weird reason, the actual window.location.replace function is not activated. The page just remains blank - upon inspection the source code displays everything correctly, and yet the redirect does not happen. If I visit the page one more time, the redirect is done fine.

If I change the name of the session variable in both files, and have to re-set it all over again, the same thing happens - upon initial visit the redirect is not processed, but clearly everything up until the actual redirect is processed correctly again.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you go to the page, the session variable isn't set yet. So the `if` will fail, and the variable assignments won't be put into the `<script>`. The browser will then perform the AJAX call that sets the session variable, but it's too late to affect that original page, you have to go to the page again to see the effect of it.

Remember, all the PHP in the page is executed on the server first, the output is sent to the browser, then the JS is executed.

I suggest you put the code that performs the redirect into the `success:` function of `$.ajax`.

Comment: That's the thing - the if does NOT fail - when I inspect the source code of the blank page, it shows the conditional JS code outputted correctly, which means the session var is set. It just does not execute the redirect for some reason. All the variables that are used for the construction of the redirect URL are set fine too.

Comment: Are you using `View Source`? That does another `GET` of the URL, so it's actually like going to the page a second time.

Comment: Yes, I was using View Source indeed - had no idea it does a second request to the page...

Comment: I added this at the end of the code to fix the issue: 

<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['allow']))  {

echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL='initial.php'\" />";   

}

?>

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several things need to be manipulated.

First of all, php itself is a template engine. What does that mean? It means it will translate php script into html as possible as it can. so this block below will be translate into html and remain static.

```
<?php

 if(isset($_SESSION['allow']))  {

   echo "var url = \"url-here/?token=\";
   var token = \"token\";
   var redirect = url.concat(token);";
 }
?>
```

That is, the redirect variable is determined before your Ajax call. That also can explain why the second time you visit the page the redirect work but not the first time.

Secondly, although you place Ajax related code before `window.location.replace` doesn't mean they will shoot in a desired order as you expect. That's because Ajax call is a async operation and you can't predict when you will get the response. In this situation I will put the `window.location.replace` thing into Ajax call successful callback like:

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url : './session.php',
  dataType: "json",
  data: "<?php echo $hash; ?>",
  success : function(data){
    window.location.replace(data.url)
  },
  error : function(){}
});
```

Third, you should detect `isset($_SESSION['allow'])` thing in server side and response in a JSON-like format:

```
{
  url: desired_url
}
```

Hope this help. Good luck.